# .htaccess RewriteRule that doesn't match directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this **.htaccess** rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3}|[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{3})/?$ /dashboard.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The $1 value can be any value that has these structures:

- **xx** / e.g.: es, en , it ,fr, ja, mww
- **xx-xxx** / e.g.: zh-cht (chinese)

So, if the user goes to:

- mydomain.com/de >> it really opens mydomain.com/dashboard.php?lang=de

That works fine... but i also have some directories inside the webroot directory that can (and will) confuse the webserver. For example:

- mydomain.com/pap >> this is a directory with some pages, and instead of recognizing it as a directory, the webserver tries to process it like mydomain.com/dashboard.php?lang=pap
- mydomain.com/img >> you get the idea...
- mydomain.com/css >> you get the idea...

The question is: how can the .htaccess avoid directories that already exist in my current rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the condition:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

right above the rule. This condition checks that the `-d` (is an existing directory) is false. So a request for a directory will fail that condition and the rule won't get executed.